# How to respect your colleagues

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, chasidut-hasidism, orach-chaim

BH

I heard there is a Mitzvah to respect your fellow colleagues what does the Torah say from the Talmud and Halacha upon this topic?

Comment: Avos 2:10 Rabbi Eliezer said: The honor of your fellow should be as dear to you as your own.

Comment: What do you mean by colleague?

Comment: Close talmidim friends like your colleagues in Yeshiva or Collel for example